# Facebook App Request "Referral"

Tags: php, facebook, apprequests

I am working on a facebook game in PHP, and one of the things I'm having trouble with is requesting friends to play.

The goal of the request system is (aside from getting them to play) to have them be "referred" by the user who sent the request.

What I want to accomplish is have the user who is requested accept the invitation, and then be listed as a referral in the database (MySQL). The database would be changed via the post-authorization page that is pinged after the user authorizes the app.

So It would be like this:

Person A sends request to B
B accepts request
Post-Add page makes B a referral of A.

I'm not sure how exactly that would be passed along. I would like for the referral change to be automatic (when person B authorizes the app and joins).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add a referral id  to the url you set for facebook to redirect to after authorizing